# How to copy paste an entire row with in the same grid in Kendo UI Jquery

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We can copy paste the value of a cell into other cells when we are batch editing . Now want to know  weather we can copy paste an entire row with in the same grid.

Found this http://www.telerik.com/forums/copy-and-paste-rows-in-kendo-ui-asp-net-mvc-grid but its between grids and requires selection and keyboard navigation to be disabled, but i need selection and keyboard navigation and selection functionality.

Comment: As fas as I understand what you want is duplicating a row, right? how do you plan to select which row to duplicate?

Comment: Select multiple rows using check boxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is working at model level. I.e. identify the data corresponding to the row that you select and then append that data to the datasource.

Since you mention in a comment that the rows being duplicated are marked with a checkbox, what you can do is:

```
// Items to insert
var items = [];
// For the rows with checked item
$(":checked", grid.tbody).each(function(idx, elem) {
     // Get the row 
     var row = $(elem).closest("tr");
     // Get the item for that row
     var item = grid.dataItem(row);
     items.push(item);
});
// Insert it in the DataSource
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    grid.dataSource.add(items[i]);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: products,
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            CheckBox: { type: "boolean" },
            ProductName: { type: "string" },
            UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
            UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
            Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 4
    },
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
      { field: "CheckBox", title:"&nbsp;", template: "<input type='checkbox'/>", width: 30 },
      "ProductName",
      { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
      { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
      { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
    ]
  }).data("kendoGrid");

  $("#duplicate").on("click", function() {
    var items = [];
    $(":checked", grid.tbody).each(function(idx, elem) {
      var row = $(elem).closest("tr");
      var item = grid.dataItem(row);
      items.push(item);
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      grid.dataSource.add(items[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/products.js"></script>
<button id="duplicate" class="k-button">Duplicate</button>
<div id="grid"></div>
```