# Kendo Grid -- Editing a row created as a duplicate one

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This question is an extension to the existing one: [How to copy paste an entire row with in the same grid in Kendo UI Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450340/how-to-copy-paste-an-entire-row-with-in-the-same-grid-in-kendo-ui-jquery)

I was able to add duplicate rows on click of a button, but the issue I am facing is I also need to edit the duplicated rows instead of the original row. Whenever I click on the cell to edit I get this error: 
**kendo.all.js:4515 Uncaught TypeError: i.wrap is not a function(…)**

I am able to edit the original rows but not able to edit the duplicated rows. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are adding the duplicate rows exactly as described in the linked question/answer...

I do not get that error when I make the grid editable: true.  You will need to provide a code sample that shows your setup and the error.

Now, having said that, I have taken the linked answer and made a Dojo from it, made the grid editable and have successfully edited the duplicate rows.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/EHeFU

Slight changes had to be made to get the editing to work properly as without them, editing the duplicate dataItem would also make the changes to the original dataItem because they have the same identifier unless you do something about it, i.e.:

```
$("#duplicate").on("click", function() {
    var items = [];
    $(":checked", grid.tbody).each(function(idx, elem) {
      var row = $(elem).closest("tr");
      // Must duplicate the raw data only using toJSON(), otherwise the duplicated item will have the same identifier(uid) as the original.
      var item = grid.dataItem(row).toJSON();
      items.push(item);
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      // You must also clear the model's id field otherwise the copy may not be treated as a new item.
      items[i].ProductID = 0;
      grid.dataSource.add(items[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks a ton!! Apparently I missed the "MUST" part you mentioned above toJSON part. Works like a charm!